# Fedora 36 login screen no icons and no cusrsor

Tags: fedora, gnome-shell, gdm

Login screen icons are not visible anymore and the cursor is a transparent white box. This happens only when in the **GDM login screen**. Icons and cursor **works fine when inside Gnome** DE.

Tried reinstalling `adawaita-cursor-theme, adawaita-icon-theme, libadwaita, gnome-shell, gnome-icon-theme and gdm` but the issue still remains. It is the same for **any** GDM theme that was tried on.

***Possible cause: installing new theme which patches libadwaita.***

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a way to find the cause / fix this?

Any help is appreciated

[image: GDM login screen]

Comment: I've never seen this issue before. As you mentioned, this might be due to the new theme that patches `libadwaita`. What happens if you switch back to the regular theme? Also, are you using X or Wayland?

Comment: I tried both X-Org and Wayland and the default Adwaita theme. Nothing changes. Must be some  bad config setting or a broken sym-link.

Comment: I have switched to KDE and switched back to Gnome and reinstalled GDM and Gnome-shell in the process. Still the issue persists.

Comment: I'm guessing it doesn't, but if you switch to KDE's login screen, does the issue persist?

Comment: No issue on KDE login screen

Comment: Can you check if one of these two commands will do the trick? `update-alternatives --config gdm-theme.gresource` and/or `update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme`

Comment: It doesn't work